Rewiring a Pendant Lamp - Cannot Get Nut and Washer off Lamp Nipple/Bolt
I purchased a pendant lamp for my kitchen, but it arrived with a cord 20" shorter than advertised. I want to rewire it with a longer cord, but I can't figure out how to disassemble the lamp.
The lamp has a giant conical metal shade with a smaller upside-down cone on top where the cord exits. The lightbulb socket is inside the large cone, covered by a metal socket cover. The cord runs through a 5" lamp nipple, with a washer and nut at the top.
When I try to unscrew the nut with a passthrough socket wrench, the nipple, washer, nut, and socket spin endlessly. Holding the socket while using the wrench causes some movement, but it feels like I might break the socket if I go further.
I suspect there's a set screw attaching the socket to the nipple, but I can't access it. I cannot figure out why the nipple, washer, but, and socket move together as one; why can't I unscrew the nut? I do not have enough room to both hold the bolt and unscrew the nut. The best I can do is hold the socket. Is there anything I can do to disassemble this without breaking the socket? Should I break the socket? If so, how could I do that? Or is the risk of not being able to replace this socket too high? If I need to return the lamp, I will, but I'd rather keep it because it took me and my partner ages to decide on a lamp.
Thank you!






That's not your common type of wire.  Have you been able to find it?

I think you're better off returning this lamp and getting one that matches the advertising... But try starting disassembly from the socket side
